# FB4 TextArea Focus Skin

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I can't get my TextArea to take the focus skin which I did in the mxml skin file below. Can anyone help me with this. Note that in my application css file I have specified the focus skin as such : focus-skin: ClassReference("skins.focusSkin");

Skin File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent;

            private var _target:SkinnableComponent;

            public function get target():SkinnableComponent
            {
                return _target;
            }

            public function set target(value:SkinnableComponent):void
            {
                _target = value;

                if (_target.skin)
                    _target.skin.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE,
                        skin_updateCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                this.setActualSize(target.width, target.height);
                super.updateDisplayList(target.width, target.height);
            } 

            private function skin_updateCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:BitmapImage id="focusGroup"             source="@Embed(source='mySkinFile.swf', symbol='mySymbol')" />

</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the examples in this blog post that demonstrates how to create custom focus skins in spark:
http://flexponential.com/2010/01/24/custom-focusskin-for-spark-components-in-flex-4/